# Html autoplay video remains muted even after clicking play (and unmuting)

Tags: javascript, html5-video

I built a landing page that autoplays a muted video when a user visits the webpage. However, sometimes when I click the big unmute button it plays the video but it's still muted.

Here is what it looks like:

[image]

and here is the video HTML:

```
<video ref={videoRef} id="vidplayer" autoPlay muted={muted} playsInline preload="auto">
    <source src={src} type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

Here is the javascript/react that is called when the unmute button is clicked.

```
let playInitialVideo = async () => {

  try{
    let video = videoRef.current;
    video.currentTime = 0 //restart the video
    await video.pause(); //pause to update to unmuted
    video.muted = false; //make sure vid is muted
    setMuted(false) //change state to muted which will change the attribute on the video html
    await video.play();

  } catch(err){
    console.error(err.message)
  }
}
```

This works fine 99% of the time, but every now and then the video plays but it stays muted unless I toggle the pause/play button again. Any idea what's going on? I expect it to play and unmute the video when I click the large unmute button.

Comment: Does clicking the video also trigger the `setMuted(false)` dispatcher? Like, when clicking the big *unmute* button?

Comment: Yes. Should I remove that? I feel like I don't even need it and that could be causing the issues.

Comment: For example, don't set mute with muted={muted} on the video element. Just update the video element directly video.muted = false.

Comment: It's hard to tell without running your code. Could you create a snippet in [repl](https://repl.it/languages/reactjs) or [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) so we can take a look. [Stack snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) are also an option, but IMO are compromising when it comes to React.js and off-site media like video's. Add the snippet to your question.